# How to Get string value between a string value

Tags: c#, winforms

"The example is for C# - The value is -Here is value."
I want to get the value(Here is value) from this string value i have tried but it will give me error when there is two (-)dash in the string value and could not able to get value. How can i do that what i have tried is.

```
        String St = "The example is for C# - The value is -Default ID.";

        int pFrom = St.IndexOf(" - ") + "-  ".Length;
        int pTo = St.LastIndexOf(" . ");
        String result = St.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
```

It work fine when there is only one(-) in sentence . How can i get the value (Default ID) from string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *Regex* pattern `[^-]*$`

**Example**

```
var input = "The example is for C# - The value is -Default ID.";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"[^-]*$");
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

**Output**

```
Default ID.
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bw8n07)

---

**Explanation**

[image]

**Visualization**

[image]

Comment: May be string have the "full stop" as well in last index.

Answer (score -1):

No need for two indices, just use the last occurrence of "-."

Try:

```
String St = "The example is for C# - The value is -Default ID.";
String result = St.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
```

If you want to remove the period at the end, you can do:

```
String finalResult = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);
```

Comment: `St.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("-") + 1)` will return "Default ID." instead of "-Default ID."